# Webdriver is not detecting when a web element becomes invisible

Tags: selenium, webdriver, visibility

I am having trouble getting this "invisibilityOfElementLocated()"  method to work.  Here is the 
code I am using and I am witnessing the element disappear after about 35 seconds with my own eyes but Webdriver does not detect this and crashes on this code and skips the test.   Would love if someone had a diffferent method that worked better.

```
if ( driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//div[@class='Caption']" )).isDisplayed() ) {
  System.out.println("Caption is visible.");
}
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait( driver , 60 ); 
wait1.until( 
  ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated( 
    By.xpath( "//div[@class='Caption']" ) 
  )
);
```

Here is the error I causes:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for
  element to no longer be visible: By.xpath: //div[@class='Caption']
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 16:53:24'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', 
  java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(
          FluentWait.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:220)
    at test.TaskListPage.isLoaded(TaskListPage.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SlowLoadableComponent.get(
         SlowLoadableComponent.java:48)
    at test.TaskListPage.<init>(TaskListPage.java:31)
    at test.Form.testLogin(Form.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(
        NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(
           DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(
          FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(
          ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(
          FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(
          InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(
          BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(
           BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(
       RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
```

Also, this method gives a similar error:

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
    WebElement tE = driver.findElement( By.className("Caption") );
    // return the invisibility instead of the visibility
    return !tE.isDisplayed();
  }
};
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
w.until(e);
```

I had some success with this but it still throws an exception when the element finally becomes invisible and then bounces me out of my test case:

```
while ( 
  // dialogMiddleCenterInner is a td that contains the Caption div
  driver.findElement( By.className("dialogMiddleCenterInner")
).isDisplayed() ) {
  System.out.println("Caption is visible.  Waiting for login.");
  AFormUtils.waitSeconds(2);
}
```

Comment: How is the element being hidden? Is it just hidden, or is it moved / destroyed? Could you possibly make a simple testcase?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't write the javascript on the site and so I don't know exactly how it is hidden.  I do know that it hides though; not only visually but because the last paragraph of my question proves it, I think...

Comment: If the Exception thrown with the last paragraph is `StaleElementReferenceException`, then I know. Otherwise, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: No, its a simple "NoSuchElementException", which basically is just saying it can no longer find the element.   If I knew how to handle the error (on the overridden isLoaded() method of LoadableComponent) so it doesn't crash my test case, then that might work for me as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Slanec for trying to help me.  Ok, this was the answer.  It seems that, whether or not I used ExpectedCondition or not, I just had to handle the exception instead of allowing it to throw, but it finally works:

```
try {
  while ( 
    // dialogMiddleCenterInner is a td that contains the Caption div
    driver.findElement( By.className("dialogMiddleCenterInner")
  ).isDisplayed() ) {
  System.out.println("Caption is visible.  Waiting for login.");
  MyUtils.waitSeconds(2);
} catch ( NoSuchElementException nse ) {
  nse.printStackTrace(); // print but simulate .ignoring() by catching exception
}
```

Comment: It seems that the element is not simply hidden, but removed from the DOM entirely / changed it's class. You can make sure this is the case in any browser's developer tools / page inspection tools.

Comment: Interesting.  So, a changing DOM must be uncommon?

Comment: Well, there is a difference between "the element became invisible" and "the element was destroyed". The former would trigger the `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated` condition, the latter makes it choke. The former would work with your solution without any `catch` block, the latter forces you to write it differently than you would like to. Actually, it can be replaced with a oneliner that checks the presence of the element: `while (driver.findElements(By.className("dialogMiddleCenterInner")).size() > 0) {}`

Answer (score 0):

**invisibilityOfElementLocated**(By locator) 
An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.

use instead,
*presenceOfElementLocated*(By locator) 
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page.